# Loading Sequence File data into hive table created using stored as sequence file failing

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

Importing the content from MySQL to HDFS as sequence files using below sqoop import command

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" 
    --username retail_dba --password cloudera 
    --table orders 
    --target-dir /user/cloudera/sqoop_import_seq/orders 
    --as-sequencefile 
    --lines-terminated-by '\n' --fields-terminated-by ','
```

Then i'm creating the hive table using the below command

```
create table orders_seq(order_id int,order_date string,order_customer_id int,order_status string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
```

But when I tried to load sequence data  obtained from 1st command into hive table using the below command

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/cloudera/sqoop_import_seq/orders' INTO TABLE orders_seq;
```

It is giving the below error.

```
Loading data to table practice.orders_seq
Failed with exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: WritableName can't load class: orders
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You have a unique file of java class "orders". From what I've read, you need to write a special Java MapReduce job to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, It's necessary to have the data in that format?

Let's suppose you have to have the data in that format. The **load data** command is not necessary. Once the sqoop finishes importing data, you will just have to create a Hive table pointing the same directory where you sqoop the data.

One side note from your scripts:

```
create table orders_seq(order_id int,order_date string,order_customer_id int,order_status string)  
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'  
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
```

Your sqoop command says this: `--fields-terminated-by ','` but when you are creating the table you are using: `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'`

In my experience, the best approach I thing is to [sqoop the data as avro](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/cdh_ig_sqoop.html), this will create automatically an avro-schema. Then you will just to have to create a Hive table using the schema previously created ([AvroSerde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AvroSerDe#AvroSerDe-WritingtablestoAvrofiles)) and using the location where you stored the data you got from sqooping process.

Comment: I'm exploring the scenario to create hive tables from sequence files. I do agree with the point you can create a hive table using "stored as sequence file"  with avro/text format.But let's assume the scenario where DB guys kept the data on staging server and you have to create hive tables based on that data then how we will handle such scenario?

Comment: Could you please share how the data you already sqooped looks like. It's just about to create a Hive table pointing to the data. In case your data is CSV I would recommend you to use CSV Serde along with your Hive table (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde)